# JQuery: post FormData AND csrf token together

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Is the `data:..` line below correct? I want to post the form data AND csrf token to a Django view function.

```
$('#file-upload').on('change', function () {
    var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
            url: currentpath,  //server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            data: {formData, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
});
```

Comment: I should point out that `{{ csrf_token }}` will only work if this code appears on the body of the template. If it's inside an imported JS file. It wont work.

Comment: There is a workaround to that as well. Define a `<div id="csrf">{{ csrf_token }}</div>` in your template file. In your imported JS file you can add the token to the FormData object as `formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to add your parameters to the FormData object (using [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29)) and as always pass the formdata object alone as the data property.

```
$('#id_image').on('change', function () {
    var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    $.ajax({
            url: currentpath,  //server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
});
```

Comment: @Philip007 my bad I used a `:` instead of a `,` to separate the params in append (too much rpg). See update.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get the 403 because of the missing token. If I comment out "processData: false" then I get `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`