# including the appended variable to the data with other variable in ajax

Tags: ajax

Hello and good day everyone, I am having a problem in ajax. I have a variable named fd that contains object. But i cant find a way to put it together with other variable in "data:". I just want to pass the data of fd and also the other variables from other inputs of my form. Thank you very much.

```
$('#register_btn').click(function(e) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = $('#image')[0].files[0];
    fd.append('image',files);

    var val1 = $('#email').val();
    var val2 = $('#firstname').val();
    var val3 = $('#middlename').val();
    var val4 = $('#lastname').val();
    var val5 = $('#emp_status').val();
    var val6 = $('input[name=date_hired]').val();
    var val7 = $('#account_type').val();
    var val8 = $('#notes').val();
    var val9 = $('#position').val();
    var val10 = $('#cp_number').val();
    var val11 = $('#tel_number').val();
    var val12 = $('#address').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process/add_employee_process.php',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            data: {email: val1, firstname: val2, middlename: val3, lastname: val4, emp_status: val5, date_hired: val6, account_type: val7, notes: val8, position: val9, cp_number: val10, tel_number: val11, address: val12,fd},
                  success:function(html) {
                    if(html=="Failed"){
                      $("#gifcheckmark").attr('src','../campfire.gif');
                      $("#gifcheckmark").css('display','inline');
                      $("#gifcheckmark").css('width','inline');
                      $("#notif_message").text("Failed");
                      $("#register_btn").css('display','none');
                      $("#decline_btn").css('display','none');
                    }
                    else{
                      $("#notif_message").text("Success");
                      $("#gifcheckmark").css('display','inline');
                      $("#gifcheckmark").css('width','inline');
                      $("#register_btn").css('display','none');
                      $("#decline_btn").css('display','none');
                      setInterval(successGif, 1600);
                      $('#qr').load('../phpqrcode/index.php');
                      $('#qr').show();
                    }
                  }
            });
        });
```

This is the form

```
<form role="form" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="box-body">

            <div class="box-header with-border col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Email </label>
              <input type="email" id="email"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Firstname </label>
              <input type="text" id="firstname"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Middlename </label>
              <input type="text" id="middlename"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Middlename">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Lastname </label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Lastname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Employee Status </label>
              <input type="text" id="emp_status"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Employee Status">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Date Hired </label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                  <input type="text" name="date_hired"  class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Account Type </label>
              <input type="text" id="account_type"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Account Type">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Notes </label>
              <input type="text" id="notes" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Notes">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Positions </label>
              <input type="text" id="position"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Positions">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Cellphone Number </label>
              <input type="text" id="cp_number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Cellphone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Telephone Number </label>
              <input type="text" id="tel_number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Telephone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="">Address </label>
              <input type="text" id="address"  class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Address">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
              <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
              <div>
                <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
              </div>
            </div>

          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="col-xs-2">
              <center><button type="button" id="confirm_btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">
                Submit
              </button></center>
          </div>

        </form>
```

This is the add_employee_process.php

```
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','cjwebsolutions');

 $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

 $target = "image/".basename($image);

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
   $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
 }else{
   $msg = "Failed to upload image";
 }

$emp_id = make_emp_id($_POST['date_hired']);
$_POST['emp_id'] = $emp_id;


// Required field names
$required_fields = array('email','firstname','middlename','lastname', 'emp_status', 'date_hired','account_type','notes','position','cp_number','tel_number','address','emp_id');

$data_insert_fields = array('email','firstname','middlename','lastname', 'emp_status', 'date_hired','account_type','notes','position','cp_number','tel_number','address','emp_id');


if (check_empty_fields($required_fields)) {
  echo "Failed";
}
else
{
    data_insert($data_insert_fields,"cj_accounts");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: post FormData AND csrf token together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761987/jquery-post-formdata-and-csrf-token-together)

Comment: is `fd` directly represents to a object or it has other properties at the same time?can you show us what `fd` looks like?

Comment: the image comes from input file on a form hope this help.

<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
                  <div>
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
                  </div>
                </div>

Comment: @LeonardVallesteros you can not use `ajax` to submit data contains files,you need to use other ways

Comment: if i remove all other variables and put only fd in "data:" the uploading of file in my php works, but not when i put the other variables.